# How to describe all things we can do with an object?

Tags: grammar, expressions, tech-writing

I want to describe a **set of functions** (which belongs to a programming language) but i'm not really sure if my sentence is correct.

> This set of functions allows us to perform many mathematical operations which go from calculating the absolute value of a given number to returning a random number between 0 and 1.

Comment: The question in your title is interesting and might be on-topic; the proof-reading request in the body of your question is unquestionably off-topic. I'd recommend you change the body of your question to match your title. You're also going to have to clarify a little: your title asks about functions specific to an object (an "object oriented" kind of question), but your quoted sentence talks about functions which can apply to "any *given* number" (a "procedural" kind of questions). So: do these functions belong to the objects, or are the objects (numbers) passed into the functions?

Comment: @DanBron   With this set of functions we can performance many mathematical tasks. I just wanted to mention 2 of them, which describe the hold functionalilty. The first is to calculate tha abolute value of a given number and the second is to return a random number. I my mother language there's an expression to do it, but I don't know it in english. Can you help me?

Comment: If this is for a software facility, the reader will be familiar with the concept of interfaces which support a group of functions, and highly-specific language to "frame" the overall document need not be used.  You simply need to use language that is not "foreign" to the software-literate user, perhaps copying terminology from another document which you feel is well-written.

Comment: Instead of "which go from calculating ... to returning...", I recommend "including calculating ... and returning ...".  The way you worded it makes it sound like the two functions you mentioned are the first and last of a range of functions, as in "all numbers from 1 to 5".

Answer (score 1):

[**Functionality**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/functionality):

> any or all of the ​operations ​performed by a ​piece of ​equipment or a ​software ​program   (-- Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

*"This functionality allows us to perform ... "*

Comment: Thank you! And the rest of the sentence is correct? I'm not sure about the part "which go from calculating ... to returning ..."

Comment: Proofreading is a punishable offence, but because of your kind comment I'd suggest: *"... many mathematical operations, ranging from calculating the absolute value of a given number to returning a random number between 0 and 1."* Now don't ask again!

Comment: By the way, do you know maybe where can I post this kind of questions? forum, blog, facebook page? Thanks